Vue js exporting data
I have a problem with my code. I want to access the value of assignmentData in file1.vue everytime after it changes in another vue file(file2.vue). You can see the code in the pictures. And the data of assignmentData changes everytime a checkbox is marked/unmarked. How do i correctly use v-bind or v-model to get the value in my second file everytime it changes.
The code of the checkbox in file1.vue:
‹div class="col-smfz-11" style="margin-top: -40рх;" ›  ‹label id="kursAusgewählt" class="checkbox-container> < input type="checkbox" :checked="assignmentData.selected" @change="update('selected', $event. target.checked)"›  ‹span class="checkmark" style="margin-left: -40px; margin-top:33px;*›&nbsp; &bsp;&bsp;&bsp;&bsp;&bsp;&bsp;&bsp;Check</span>
The update function:update (key, value) { this.assignmentData[key] = value; this. $emit('update:assignmentData', this.assignmentData);
And in file2.vue how do i access this LIVE(!!!) data?
It was always showing undefined when i tried to access via v-bind

why not to use defineModel ?

whats the connection between file1 and file2? You can see the code in the pictures. no ... and the code you posted is hard to read

Its just about i have a boolean value in my props of file1 that changes when a checkbox is marked or not. How do i acces this value on a second file when the checkbox is marked.

@AlexanderNenashev what do ypu mean

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html
